# Google translate is not working on vue, its thowing error on TranslateElement

Tags: vue.js, google-translate

Google translate in vue is throwing below the exemption

```
vue.esm.js?efeb:1897 TypeError: google.translate.TranslateElement is not a constructor
```

Here is my code, is there anything I am missing?

Javascript

```
created () { 
   this.loadDropdown();

   window.google = document.createElement('script');    
   google.setAttribute('src',"//translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit");
   document.head.appendChild(google);

   this.googleTranslateElementInit();
}



 methods: {
   googleTranslateElementInit() {
    new google.translate.TranslateElement(
     {pageLanguage: 'en'},
     'google_translate_element'
    );
   },
},
```

Template

```
<div class="google_translate" id="google_translate_element"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

jsonp callback must be global(window) scope.
u can try this:

```js
methods: {
   createJsonpCallback() {
       window.googleTranslateElementInit() {
        new google.translate.TranslateElement(
         {pageLanguage: 'en'},
         'google_translate_element'
        );
       },
   }
},
```